Jspdf & Html2canvas -Image cut off while pdf contents "multiple" pages
I need to generate PDF from my web site page.
I have used JSPDF and HTML2Canvas for the same.
When I have tried to generate the PDF with large amount of data and image it has split image in 2 diffrent page. Please check attached screenshot for better understanding.
PDF Output
Below is my code snippet,
 const handleDownloadPDF = async () => {
    const cleanedDescription = description.replaceAll(/<\/?b>/g, '');
    const replacedDescription = cleanedDescription.replaceAll('&#58;', ':');

    const containerWithPadding = document.createElement("div");
    containerWithPadding.style.padding = "20px";

    const container = document.createElement("div");
    container.style.color = "#000000";
    container.innerHTML = replacedDescription;

    const spanElements = container.querySelectorAll("span");
    spanElements.forEach(span => {
      span.style.color = "#000000";
    });

    const imageElements = Array.from(container.querySelectorAll("img"));

    await Promise.all(imageElements.map(async img => {
      const imageUrl = img.src;
      const imageData = await fetch(imageUrl).then(res => res.blob());
      const dataUrl = await blobToDataURL(imageData);
      img.src = dataUrl;
    }));

    containerWithPadding.appendChild(container);

    const urlParts = window.location.pathname.split('/');
    const fileName = urlParts[urlParts.length - 1];

    html2pdf().from(containerWithPadding).save(`${project}_${fileName}.pdf`);
  };

  const blobToDataURL = (blob) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result);
      reader.onerror = reject;
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    });
  };

Can anyone help me with the same?
Thanks in Advance
I need to generate PDF without split image in different page.

Do you want to create a new page break, instead of splitting the image?

Yes, either I need to set the image on the same page without splitting the image or I need to create a new page and put the image on that page.
